# Changing div content by clicking on arrow button

Tags: jquery

I want to change div content by clicking on arrow button like in character creator.

- First click on arrow - display "text",
- second click - "text2",
- third click - display first content "text".

I have tried to write this by myself but it always doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have shown us *no* code. We cannot help you if we have nothing to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It uses an array to determine which string should be displayed when the button is clicked. You can add additional strings into the array and it will still work correctly.

```
var strings = ["Text", "Text 2"];
var clicks = 0;
$("#arrow").click(function(){
    $("#divtochange").text(strings[clicks%strings.length]);
    clicks++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/be3o264t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition in this scenario.

Like this:

```
var clickCount = 1;

$('#arrow').click(function(){
   if((clickCount%2) == 0){
      $('#divId').text('text1');
   } else {
      $('#divId').text('text2');
   }
   clickCount++;
});
```

You should change the id of selector according to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, first bet could be to try such code typically :

```
var count=0;
$('.arrow-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (count==0)  {
        $('.text-div').html('text2');
        count=1;
    } else {
        $('.text-div').html('text1');
        count=0;
    }
});
```